# How to design/persist user roles (current & signed up) for a multi-user java app?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-design, user-roles, multi-user

I'm building an app that allows each user to select whether they want to register as a player, and optionally as an admin. They can register as both a player AND an admin, but can only have ONE current role -> i.e. can only log in as either player/admin at the given time.

I'm using a Player-Role pattern in which Player and Admin class  **extend**  the abstract UserRole class.

What table structure should I create to support this in a way that:

- I can store a list of the roles the user has registered for
- I can store and retrieve on demand the CURRENT User Role for User

For example, I would like to have the following code be supported by database to get the current Role of user in Player.getRole() and one similar one for Admin.getRole():

```
        User userWithID = User.getUser(userWithID);
        UserRole playerRole = null;
        List<UserRole> userRoles = userWithID.getRoles();
        for(UserRole role : userRoles){
            if(role instanceof Player){
                playerRole = role;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(playerRole == null) throw new IllegalAccessError("Player with ID does not exist");
        else{
            return (Player) playerRole;
        }
```

The problem arises that i need two kinds of information from user roles. 1- the roles registered for, and 2- the current role. And UserRole is abstract.

**NB: Before you mark this as duplicate:** 
All the other questions on StackOverflow don't have answers that indicate how to get the current user role for a user, or don't have implementations specified under this domain model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged [database-design](/questions/tagged/database-design), I'll show a possible table design for that:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
   role_id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE user_has_role (
   user_id bigint REFERENCES users NOT NULL,
   role_id bigint REFERENCES roles NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id)
);

CREATE TABLE current_role (
   user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users,
   role_id NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (user_id, role_id) REFERENCES user_has_role
);
```

The first three tables contain the static information and the fourth us updated whenever the user logs in.